# Objects passed to React Native via native module callback parameters in Swift are null

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, react-native, react-native-native-module

I am successfully calling a JavaScript callback in a Swift native module in React Native. I need to pass data from the Native side back to React Native, but when the data is anything other than strings or numbers, the data parameter in the callback is `null`. I need to pass back an array of objects as a parameter but for testing purposes I have created an instance of a Swift class:

```swift
    func displayProviderDialog(_ mvpds: [Any]) {
        
        class City: NSObject {
            var name: String = "TEST STRING"
        }
        
        var city = City();
        
        rNCallbacks.displayProviderDialogCallback([mvpds, city])
    }
```

The in Typescript on the React Native side:

```
export function displayProviderDialog(MVPDs: unknown[], city: any) {
    console.log(`${JSON.stringify(MVPDs)} >>>>>>>>>>>>> ${JSON.stringify(city)}}`
    );
}
```

Both `MVPDs` and `city` are `null` in React Native, but are not null in Swift / Xcode.

How can I pass back arrays and objects from Swift native modules to React Native?

Comment: I'm not sure if user-created objects are supported.  You could stringify it as JSON on the native side and parse it in JS, slightly annoying but quite reliable

Comment: Ok thanks - I’ve been trying that and not been able to do it - what I need to pass back is ‘mvpds’ which is ‘[Any]’ - do you know how I can stringify that?

Comment: Since `any` can be anything, no, I do not know exactly how to do that.  But your `City` would be `"{\"name\":\"TEST STRING\"}"`

Comment: Thanks @Abe, that example seems like a string literal, I would need some way of  stringifying the object at runtime with somekind of method

Comment: Exactly, you could do this manually or find a library in your native language that does it